# Wordpress time format for a blog post is damaged

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the theme: Dreame and I really like it, but there's one problem with it. The date is displayed as follows:

`%A, 12UTCThu, 12 Dec 2013 20:56:27 +0000 %e. %B %Y`

I don't know why this problem exists. I checked in the editor the single.php and this is how the time for the post is retrieved

`<span class="TzCreate"><?php the_date(); ?></span>`

Where would I fix this problem?

Comment: Probably a bad combination of `strftime()` and `date()` in a template somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the format (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date):

`<?php the_date( $format, $before, $after, $echo ); ?>`

How to format:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

Change it to:

`<span class="TzCreate"><?php the_date('l, F j, Y'); ?></span>`

Which will show:

**Thursday, December 12, 2013**

Comment: Thansk! That was exactly the problem. Now I only have to find every occurance! How could they miss this?

Comment: Honestly, check the `functions.php` file in the theme, I bet there is a hook in there modifying this globally. So you can modify it in one spot.